# Decorate injected service instance

Tags: angularjs, logging, angular-services

I'm trying to prepend the name of the "object" where a log occures to every log.

For example, I inject the $log service to "myService". I want it to prepend "myService" to every log :

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .factory('myService', ['$log', function($log) {
        return {
            myFunction = function() {
                $log.warn('Content of my warning message');
            };
        };
    }]);
```

So when I call 'myService.myFunction()' it logs :

```
[myService] Content of my warning message
```

How can an injected instance know where it is injected? Furthermore, the injected instances are singletons, so is it even possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work the `$log` service would need to know the environment in which it resides, obviously it doesn't have that information, because the injected dependencies are not "informed" where are they being injected.